# How make stringConnection throw a txt file MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Is there a way to acomplish that? I know how to do it with the web.config file but I was told that cannot be in web.config cuz it must be in a text file where the connection string must be.

Here is what i have tried:

```
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings configSource="ConexionBaseDeDatos.txt"></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Similar like if i'd it use the a .config file like this

```
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings configSource="ConexionBaseDeDatos.config"></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And the base name

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace appSwicth.Models {
    public class ConexionBaseDeDatos:DbContext {

        DbContext db;
        public ConexionBaseDeDatos() :base()
        {



        }
    }
}
```

But I got an error:

"Root Element is missing"

And then the url of the file and nothing more.(the url is totally correct). In the txt file i have nothing now. Could that be the reason of why? I added a connectiong string to it but still not worked, maybe im doing something wrong.

Any way to solve this? If you need more, let me know.

Comment: Did you try it by adding a `Application Setting` like this `<add key="ConexionBaseDeDatos" value="ConexionBaseDeDatos.txt"/>` ?

Comment: I tried but i couldnt find out how to do it. I tried like this <connectionStrings >
<add key="ConexionBaseDeDatos" value="ConexionBaseDeDatos.txt"/>
        
    </connectionStrings> but it doesnot work

Comment: As per my understanding this is not possible after looking at MSDN too. But still you have got the way to do it. Please let us know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the Standard Format to mention the **External Configuration** file only.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="Your_File_Name.config"/>
</configuration>
```

It's self explanatory from it's name Config Source
The Source belongs to Configuration files only.

**[From MSDN - Storing and Retrieving Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms254494%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

**Alternative - From the above comments**

Fetch the information from App Settings like below.

```
<add key="ConexionBaseDeDatos" value="ConexionBaseDeDatos.txt"/>
```